# How can I generate docker-compose.yml with Rancher v2?

Tags: docker-compose, rancher

I need to generate docker-compose.yml. 
I have a container running on Rancher v2 with Kubernetes but I find only the possibility to get rancher-compose instead of docker-compose. I remember that with Rancher 1.6 with Cattle there was the possibility to get docker-compose.

Any suggestions? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

2.x is kubernetes and takes/produces only kubernetes yaml manifests, not docker- (or rancher-) compose.

Comment: How can I take a fast solution for a docker compose without write with my hands? Thank you